# Best practice authentication when working with WCF web services

Tags: wcf, authentication, service

I am looking at adding a custom authentication for my WCF web service and is wondering which the "industry standard" best practice for web service authentication is? I need the web service to be supported from many different coding platforms with minor configuration.

Thanks!

Comment: What custom authentication do you mean? Did you check standard authentication mechanism offered by WCF?

Answer (score 1):

Look into WSS - WS-* by OASIS.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security